# How to apply tickStrategy formatter only for one axis in LightningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, charts, lightningchart

I created a chart with lightningChart JS and would like to format my y axis tick labels.

The normal way to do should be to use the `tickStrategy.formatValue` function:

```
const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY()

axisY.tickStrategy.formatValue = (value, range) => {
      return value + ' Y';
};
```

If I do so, both axis labels are formatted (X, Y) instead of only y axis.

[image: lightningChartJS tick label formatter example]

So my questions is how to apply the formatter only for one axis?

Please see my snippet, where I try to change the labels for x and y. But one overrides the other for both axes.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY()

const tickX = axisX.tickStrategy.formatValue = (value, range) => {
             return value + ' X';
             };
             
const tickY = axisY.tickStrategy.formatValue = (value, range) => {
             return value + ' Y';
             };
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, the solution is simple, but not really obvious.

I have to create a default axis strategy and make a copy of the Numeric defaultAxisXTickStrategy with `Object.assign({})`.

```
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: Object.assign({}, AxisTickStrategies.Numeric)
})
```

After that the formatter function has the expected behavior.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    AxisTickStrategies
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: Object.assign({}, AxisTickStrategies.Numeric)
});

const axisX = chart.getDefaultAxisX();
const axisY = chart.getDefaultAxisY();

const tickX = axisX.tickStrategy.formatValue = (value, range) => {
             return value + ' X';
             };
             
const tickY = axisY.tickStrategy.formatValue = (value, range) => {
             return value + ' Y';
             };
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```